# Exception Value: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

`enter code here`TypeError at /polls/
**join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function'**
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
**join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function'**
Exception Location: c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\genericpath.py, line 152, in _check_arg_types

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Question, choice
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question=get_object_or_404(Question ,pk=question_id)
    return render(request, detail,{'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/result.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{
            'question: question'
            'error_message': "you didn't select a choice."
            })
    else:
        selected_choice.vote += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:result', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: i am unable to resolve this error i mean i am not correctly understanding the error

Comment: refer to python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your view responsible for handling the 'polls' endpoint you're causing the string join method to be called on a function object. Please post your source code and full stack trace.